# operator.attrgetter cannot read attributes in a dataclass

Tags: python

I have a module that holds a dataclass:

my_module.py

```
@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    foo: str
    bar: str
```

I want to use `operator.attrgetter` to read `MyDataClass.foo`

```
import package.my_module
from operator import attrgetter

obj = attrgetter('MyDataClass.foo')(package.my_module)  # error!
```

attrgetter throws `AttributeError: type object 'MyDataClass' has no attribute 'foo'`.

Is there something else I should be using instead of `operator.attrgetter`?

Comment: Those describe attributes of _instances_, not of the class.

Comment: What value did you expect to get when you haven't assigned anything to those attributes?

Answer (score 0):

The **attrgetter** from the **operator** module is typically used for instances, not for accessing attributes on the class itself. Since MyDataClass is a class, you can access its attributes directly without using attrgetter.

*Example of using attrgetter*

```py
from package.my_module import MyDataClass

# create an instance of MyDataClass
obj_instance = MyDataClass(foo="value1", bar="value2")

# access the 'foo' attribute directly
foo_value = obj_instance.foo
print(foo_value)
```

#### So want to use attrgetter for some reason, you can create an instance of MyDataClass and then use attrgetter.